# Wordpress functions built into Notepad++

Tags: php, wordpress, notepad++

I code PHP in Wordpress quite a bit and would love my editor, Notepad++ to be able to show wordpress functions on the fly with autocomplete. Possible?

Comment: You need a real IDE for that like PHPStorm, Netbeans, Zend Studio whatsoever

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/danchivz/notepad-plus-plus-wordpress-auto-complete), it contains about 900 global functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possibe, Please follow this article

http://takien.com/blog/2013/10/13/wordpress-autocomplete-for-notepad-plus/

https://github.com/takien/WordPress-Auto-complete-for-Notepad-Plus